# How to get a specific key which stored in redis by flask-caching

Tags: python, caching, flask, redis, flask-cache

In my flask app, I used flask-caching to cache the query result as below:

```
@cache.memoize()
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(user_id)
```

But when I access my redis, the key is like `flask_cache_L4kZRWHNrZYUZ8uyY7Mh0i`.
It's seem very hard to query the redis database to test. Because if I need the value of that key, I must be use the function `cache.get(<key>)` that in [Flask-Caching API](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#cache-api)

So I want to ask wherether it has a way to find the key of return value of a function under decorator `cache.memoize`?